# error when include angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i try to learn angular js.
i try a simple code in the html like this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Title Page</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" >
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <div>hello{(name)}</div>
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the result when i run it on web browser is an error. it didnt work
the error on console is like this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined on line 2
```

how come i get error like this?

Comment: try to including this script tag  `<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include all the `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/` page, you need to choose which script you want to include, something like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Also, it is `{{name}}` (two curly braces), not `{(name)}`

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Title Page</title>
            
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <div>hello {{name}}</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pointing to the [AngularJS CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/) page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/"></script>
```

You should select a version. For example Minified AngularJS version 1.5.8:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that you should exclude the `https`.

Also check that to print out a variable in AngularJS you should use `{{ name }}` instead of `{(name)}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two points that need to be highlighted here.

- **Your import.** The other answers are describing perfectly why it does not work. Fix it.
- **Angular itself.** Angular works with **applications** and **controllers** (for its simplest part). What you need to do is to make a file which will contain your controller. For example, create a file called `myapp.js` and import it into your web page:

`<script src="path/to/myapp.js"></script>`

Then, once you initialized your application (`var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);` will do the trick perfectly) and controller (check the [AngularJS documentation about it](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)), you'll be able to intialize your data with your scope:

`$scope.name = 'John';`

Call your application in your HTML page:

`<html ng-app="myApp">`

And you'll be able to see the magic working there:

`hello {{ name }} // and not {( name )}`

Your web browser should actually display:

`hello John`